# Почему bool не меняется при побитовых операциях? C++

Tags: c++, битовые-операции

В C++ bool весит 1 байт. Я решил для изучения побитовых операций сделать программу, которая позволит хранить 8 значений True/False в одном bool (Практической пользы это не несет, это только для тренировки). И наткнулся на интересное поведение. Сначала приведу код:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void setBool(bool &bb, int bit, bool setter) {

    bit--; // 1

    if (setter) { // true

        cout << "1: " << (bb | (1 << bit)) << "\n"; // Выводит 3, все верно
        bb |= (1 << bit); // 0000 0001 | 0000 0010 = 0000 0011

    }
    else {

        bb &= ~(1 << bit);

    }

}

int main() {

    bool bb = true; // 0000 0001

    setBool(bb, 2, true); // bb = 0000 0011

    cout << "2: " << bb << "\n"; // Выводит 1 !!

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

При вызове функции и передаче ей переменной проверяется, хочу я установить 1 или 0 и в какой байт. Далее выбирается этот байт и если я хочу вставить 1, то выполняется побитовое "И" переменной с единицей, побитово сдвинутой влево на нужное число бит. И здесь начинается прикол. Если запихнуть Выражение (bb | (1 << bit)) в std::cout, то выведет закономерно 3. Однако после этого, если вывести саму переменную bb в консоль, то выведет 1. Почему?

Comment: 1) `bool` может хранить всего два значения — это `true` и `false`. Ничего другого туда записать нельзя. 2) Если у вас возник соблазн переинтерпретировать память, в которой хранится `bool`, как имеющую тип `char`, и записать туда что-нибудь, то это плохая идея. Стандарт не специфицирует какие битовые паттерны кодируют значения `true` и `false`. 3) В C++ `bool` занимает _как минимум_ один байт, но может и больше.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому что это же не `int` и не `unsigned char`, а `bool`.

Абелева переменная принимает два значения - false или true. Все, что не 0, превращается в true, а выводится как 1 - пока не зададите формат boolalpha.

Работайте с `unsigned char`. Хранить в `bool` - пусть оно и реализовано как `unsigned char` - 8 значений - некорректно. Кстати, компилятор при включенных предупреждениях должен был об этом сообщить.

Comment: Но как измененная bool хранится в памяти? Это только выводится 1, а вы памяти переменная равно 3 или же при при логическом "И" и присвоении сразу преобразуется обратно в единицу?

Comment: А это уж как компилятор захочет. В стандарте требования к `bool` хранить 8 бит нет. Как нет и запрета...